# Load every view controllers in tab view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using [carbonKit](https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit) to create a tab view, which contains a dynamic number of tabs. The problem is, each view controller (table views controllers) is loading its content only when I'm going to the tab. I'd like to know if I could load every tabs' content (init and load every view controllers) to navigate flowlessly between each tab.

Here is the code where I init a view controller for a specific tab at index:

```
- (UIViewController *)tabSwipeNavigation:(CarbonTabSwipeNavigation *)tabSwipe viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
CommentsTableViewController *tab = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabController"];
[tab setPeople:self.peoplepassed];
[tab setQuestion:self.questionpassed];

switch (index) {
    case 0:
         [tab setTab:@1];
        break;
    case 1:
        [tab setTab:@2];
        break;
    case 2:
        [tab setTab:@3];
        break;
    case 3:
        [tab setTab:@4];
        break;
    default:
        [tab setTab:@1];
        break;
}


return tab;
}
```

Comment: Try initializing the `CommentsTableViewController` and other View Controllers (contained in the `tab`) in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Why do you wish to waste memory loading tabs that the user may not even access?

Comment: I'll try that S1LENT WARRIOR

maddy: Because the load time may be quite long for each tab, and I don't want the flow to be broken and the UI stuck every time the user swipes a tab (just like bbc news does for their app for exemple)

Comment: You should look into why each tab takes too long. Make sure you are not doing any Internet access on the main thread or something bad like that.

Comment: maddy: It's doing internet access but I have a loader to wait for it to load everything and then display content in a table view after doing some treatment of the data. I can't really load it dynamically this time since I have to get everything downloaded before showing it (the treatment involves reorder/sorting)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by the creator of carbonkit [here](https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit/issues/34), should have thought of it earlier, thanks, closed !

EDIT: will mark my own answer as resolved as I have to wait for 2 days

Comment: This works but you're conflating what I think are two distinct concerns into a single operation here: the loading of the data for each tab and the display of that views of that data. You might find it useful to separate the act of loading data which will then be provided by some `UITableViewDataSource` from the act of instantiating a `UITableView` and populating it from those data sources.

Comment: You're right, I think I'll do the loading then populate with the data when I switch tab. I'll check on that, thanks